# int_case leads to missing number problem when using multiple digits

Tags: expl3

Somehow my code breaks with `Missing number, treated as zero`...

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\Hsatz}[1]{%
    \int_case:nn { #1 }{
        { 225 } { abc }
        { 319​ } { def }
        { 336 } { ghi }
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    \Hsatz{225}
    \Hsatz{319}
    \Hsatz{336}
    
\end{document}
```

It seems to be connected to using multiple digits. The code works when I use only single digits. How can I fix this? I definitely need more than 10 options in my final code and really want to use three digits...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The white space must be spaces tabs or newlines but you have a zero width space, U+200B,  after 319, see

https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?%20%20%7B%20319%E2%80%8B%20%7D

Comment: That is very strange. I now have removed the space with backspace and added a new space and it still does not work. Removing the space and then running the conversion from your linkand the adding space again worked... Could it be my keyboard that is acting up?

Comment: @mrCarnivore you had two characters betwwen `319` and `}` one normal space U+0020 and one zero width space U+200B  if you delete the latter then the code will work. I can't tell you how you entered the zero width space, perhaps you caught some editor key combination to add it, or perhaps you cut and pasted it from somewhere.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep an eye on it. Thank you very much! I would definitely not have found it without your help. Thanks also for the analysis link. Will use that in the future.

Comment: I wrote that page a while ago, I keep it up to date with unicode releases @mrCarnivore

Answer (score 3):

If you are using pdflatex then the next error message gives the right clue on what is possibly wrong:

```
./Untitled-4.tex:21: LaTeX Error: Unicode character ​ (U+200B)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

with lualatex or xelatex this doesn't work as the Unicode engines accept any Unicode character and therefore do not bark when coming across something strange.

What also can help is to surround the offending definition with

```
\tl_analysis_show:n{
  \newcommand{\Hsatz}[1]{%
    ...
}
```

This also shows the problem, but not in a very easily identifying way:

```
...
>  \int_case:nn (control sequence=\long macro:#1#2->\exp:w \exp_args:Nf \ETC.)
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  # (macro parameter character #)
>  1 (the character 1)
>  } (end-group character })
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  2 (the character 2)
>  2 (the character 2)
>  5 (the character 5)
>  } (end-group character })
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  a (the letter a)
>  b (the letter b)
>  c (the letter c)
>  } (end-group character })
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  3 (the character 3)
>  1 (the character 1)
>  9 (the character 9)
>  ​ (the character ​)
>  } (end-group character })
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  d (the letter d)
>  e (the letter e)
>  f (the letter f)
...
```

You can see that there is a non-displaying character after `319`.
Perhaps the code for `\tl_analysis_show:n`could be improved to show the Unicode number for characters in addition.

Again with pdftex is is much more easy to identify the issue in that case:

```
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  3 (the character 3)
>  1 (the character 1)
>  9 (the character 9)
>  â (active character=\protected macro:->\UTFviii@three@octets â)
>   (active character=\protected macro:->\UTFviii@invalid@err )
>   (active character=\protected macro:->\UTFviii@invalid@err )
>  } (end-group character })
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  d (the letter d)
>  e (the letter e)
```